# How to fetch 'KeyValue' from Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, grid

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowCustomPaging="True"
    GridLines="None" PageSize="20" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" ClientSettings-Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" onneeddatasource="radGrid_NeedDataSource" OnItemCreated="radGrid_ItemCreated"
    OnItemDataBound="radGrid_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="radGrid_ItemCommand"
    DataKeyNames="ClientID">
    <mastertableview datakeynames="ID" gridlines="None" width="100%">
    <PagerTemplate> and so on ... </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**Scenario** : - *Given above is the markup of a Telerik RagGrid control I am using. I tried to access the KeyValue of the GridColumn, the usual way,*

```
Int32 key = Convert.ToInt32((e.Item as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
```

**This is not working. Is there an alternate?**

Comment: Why you specify `DataKeyNames` property on RadGrid? Try to remove it and retain it only for `MasterTableView`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        // NORMAL MODE
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        string strId = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
    }

    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {

        if (e.Item is GridEditFormInsertItem)
        {
            // INSERT MODE
            GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

        }
        else
        {
            // EDIT MODE
            GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            string strId = editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();

        }

    }
}


protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "YourCommandName")
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        string strId = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If above code is not worked for you then please please tell me in which event you want to assess this datakey.

Comment: If you found the problem, why don't you post the solution?

Comment: @MontyPython, Can you please provide more information about your Issue/Problem?

Comment: hi, i tried this code. but it always return null value on GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
string keyValue = radGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.item.ItemIndex].ToString();
int key = Convert.ToInt32(keyValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your data key in markup:

```
< MasterTableView datakeynames="ID" dir="RTL">< /MasterTableView>
```

and access in code behind:

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

var key = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a datakey that is not even specified in the radgrid markup:

```
DataKeyNames="ClientID"

Int32 key = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID"));
```

It should be:

```
Int32 key = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("ClientID"));
```

Comment: Why should it be 'ClientID'. It can be DataKeyNames="ID, Name, City, etc, etc, etc".

Comment: We access our data via mastertableview datakeynames and not radgrid datakeynames.

Comment: I saw it defined as "ClientID" on the markup. I suggested to change the code where you retrieved the value as well to match the defined keyname. Thats it. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: You're right. But I just wanted to say that we can also give multiple DataKeyNames and access them as we need them. DataKeyNames="ID,Name,Address,Country"; in this case, 4 different DataKeyNames have been declared. All can be used in separate statements

Comment: Yes, that's very possible indeed.